# Getting slope of a line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am preparing for an entrance exam and am focussing on co-ordinate geometry. However, one question has me stumbled:

> If the line $\ell$ intersects the curve $\frac{y}2 = x^2 - 7$ at $(2,a)$ and $(1, b)$ then what is the slope of line $\ell$?

I am confused with the above equation and am having a hard time tackling this question. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Arthur I am sure that's what the OP meant, took the liberty of changing the question while editing it.

Comment: Yes that’s what I meant. Thanks for the edit. Let me go through the hint in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Well, if the line $\ell$ intersects the curve $y/2 = x^2-7$ that means they share points, i.e., the intersection points lie both on the line and on the curve. You are told there are 2 such intersection points.

One of them is $(2,a)$, so is satisfies the curve and you must have
$$
\frac{a}{2} = 2^2-7 \iff a = 2\left(2^2-7\right) = -6.
$$

Can you continue?

Comment: Yeah it makes total sense. Since both the points lie on the line, I can plug in the co ordinates in the equation and get the value for the missing a and b coordinates and find the slope. Thanks for the easy and clear explanation :)

Comment: What answer did you get?

Comment: @NinetyNines let's play the other way -- what answer did *you* get?

Comment: I got the pairs $(1, -12)$ and $(2, -6)$. I got a slope of 6. @gt6989b

Comment: @NinetyNines agree, +1

Comment: @NinetyNines I got the slope as 6

Comment: @gt6989b - I have a general question about the slope of a line: suppose that the slope of a line is $m = \frac{2}{3}$, then is saying “the rate of change is two units of $y$ per three units of $x$“ equivalent to saying “the rate of change is two-thirds units of $y$ per $1$-unit of $x$”  by converting to a *unit rate*?

Comment: @TaylorRendon yes, -- the key is that both give the same proportion

Comment: @gt6989b - Gotcha! So (using meters/second) "two meters per three seconds" is the same as "two-thirds meters per second" since they both give the same proportion? Thank you for your time, as well.

Comment: @TaylorRendon correct!